# Extend an incorrect Typescript class definition

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

I'm using the NPM package [next-routes](https://github.com/fridays/next-routes/) in my project. The default export is a class which has a type definition like so:

```
export default class Routes implements Registry {
  getRequestHandler(app: Server, custom?: HTTPHandler): HTTPHandler;
  add(name: string, pattern?: string, page?: string): this;
  add(pattern: string, page: string): this;
  add(options: { name: string; pattern?: string; page?: string }): this;
  Link: ComponentType<LinkProps>;
  Router: Router;
}
```

Full file can be found in the package [here](https://github.com/fridays/next-routes/blob/master/typings/next-routes.d.ts).

This class definition is missing one of the methods that is exposed in the package's default export called `findAndGetUrls`. How do I extend the class definition with my own type for this? I thought about creating my own class that implements NextRoutes but defines the missing method definition like so:

```
import NextRoutes from 'next-routes';

class Routes implements NextRoutes {
  findAndGetUrls(
    nameOrUrl: string,
    params: {
      [key: string]: string;
    },
   ): void;
}
```

But this errors: `Function implementation is missing or not immediately following the declaration.`

**EDIT**

My new attempt is to create a `typings/next-routes.d.ts` file in my project with the following:

```
import NextRoutes from 'next-routes';

declare module 'next-routes' {
  class Routes extends NextRoutes {
    findAndGetUrls(
      nameOrUrl: string,
      params: {
        [key: string]: string;
      },
    ): void;
  }

  export = Routes;
}
```

This makes my code happy about the usage of findAndGetUrls, but now it complains that none of the other methods exist so it's not extending the types correctly. e.g. `Property 'add' does not exist on type 'Routes'.`

Comment: Shouldn't you use `extends` instead of `implements`?

Comment: @rickdenhaan I don't know, should I? I was just doing a similar thing to what they do in the next-routes package (i.e. the code snippet at the start of my question)

Comment: Should I create a `next-routes.d.ts` file and somehow improve the type definition but not completely rewrite it?

Comment: Yes, their class "implements" `Registry` because `Registry` is an interface. You're not implementing an interface, but adding functions to a class. You do that using `extends`.

Comment: Your file can be called anything as long as it ends in `.d.ts` since it's just a type declaration and not an actual implementation.

Comment: Okay. So if I create a next-routes.d.ts, should I use the `declare module 'next-routes' {...}` syntax and if so, how would I then make sure it uses the existing definition but add my new definition of the method?

Comment: @rickdenhaan I've updated my question with my newest attempt but I don't think I'm doing it right yet.

Comment: If you find a incomplete type definition of an NPM package, you really should submit a PR that fills in the missing definition.

Comment: @Mu-TsunTsai unfortunately, this package seems to be reasonably abandoned. It already has three open pull requests to fix type definitions that have been waiting for a maintainer to merge them for quite some time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been playing around with it for a while, Typescript won't allow you to redefine the class. But, it seems to work if you re-export the default as an *interface* instead of a class:

**custom-next-routes.d.ts**:

```
import NextRoutes, { RouteParams } from "next-routes";

declare module "next-routes" {
    export default interface Routes extends NextRoutes {
        findAndGetUrls(nameOrUrl: string, params: RouteParams): void;
    }
}
```

You still have to name it `Routes` so that Typescript knows to merge it with the `export default class Routes implements Registry` from the `next-routes` package.

I've only tried this on the latest Typescript version (3.5.2 currently) so YMMV if you're using an older version.

Comment: You, my friend, are a genius. I even found an existing PR to fix this problem that's been sitting in the project for 5 months (https://github.com/fridays/next-routes/pull/283/files#diff-cd5dd0092a317d3944dffafa16f1647b). I guess the package is indeed abandoned (kind of strange with 47k monthly downloads). At least I could steal a better definition from the PR anyway.