# How do I extend the default type of NPM packages?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0, typescript-generics, typescript1.8

We can use the "declare module" to extend the type of module.

**eg:**

```
// typings/node-fetch.d.ts
import 'node-fetch';
declare module 'node-fetch' {
    function kk(): void;
}

// src/index.ts
import fetch, { kk } from 'node-fetch';
kk(); // ok
```

But this is an extension of functionality.

Now I want to extend fetch itself.

I want to have this effect:

```
// src/index.ts
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
fetch.foo();
```

The declaration file for node-fetch itself looks like this:

```
// node_modules/@types/node-fetch/index.d.ts
declare function fetch(
    url: RequestInfo,
    init?: RequestInit
): Promise<Response>;

declare namespace fetch {
    function isRedirect(code: number): boolean;
}

export default fetch;
```

How can I extend the type of fetch?

I tried it. It doesn't work:

```
// typings/node-fetch.d.ts
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

declare module 'node-fetch' {
    namespace fetch {
        function foo(): void;
    }
    export default fetch; // Error, Exports and export assignments are not permitted in module augmentations
}
```

How would you like to solve it, please.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you need to do is use the interface keyword as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56861261/106625 –

Comment: Thanks! But it can't solve it. I want to use 'fetch.kk', this way you get is going to be an interface.Anything else please?