# Typescript add missing methods to exported library class

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, types

In the [snoowrap](https://github.com/not-an-aardvark/snoowrap) library they have a custom [.d.ts file](https://unpkg.com/browse/snoowrap@1.21.0/dist/snoowrap.d.ts), but the exported Snoowrap class is missing a `getContentByIds()` method. How can I add that method in my own type declaration file?

I tried multiple SO answers, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56857826/extend-an-incorrect-typescript-class-definition), and created my own `snoowrap.d.ts` but that doesn't work:

```js
// snoowrap.d.ts
import snoowrap, { Comment, Submission, Listing } from 'snoowrap';

declare module 'snoowrap' {
    export default interface Snoowrap extends snoowrap {
        getContentByIds(ids: Array<string | Submission | Comment>): Promise<Listing<Submission | Comment>>
    }
}
```

My code:

```js
// main.ts
import snoowrap from 'snoowrap';
const reddit = new snoowrap();
const submissions = await reddit.getContentByIds(['t3_9l9vof']);
```

My error:

`Property 'getContentByIds' does not exist on type 'import("project/node_modules/snoowrap/dist/snoowrap.d.ts")'.ts(2339)`

Comment: Where did you put the `snoowrap.d.ts` file? Is it's path inside the `include` on the `tsconfig.json` ?

Comment: @MarioGarcia I have it in my /src/types folder. My tsconfig.json has `"typeRoots": ["./src/types", "./node_modules/@types"]`.

I have a separate types.d.ts in the same folder and those types work fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you check the content of `node_modules/snoowrap/dist/snoowrap.d.ts` you'll see that the class `Snoowrap` is not defined within a `namespace`, also it doesn't have an interface. So I think in order to override this class with new functions you should try the snipped below:

```js
// snoowrap.d.ts
import {default as SnoowrapClass, Comment, Submission, Listing } from 'snoowrap';

export default class Snoowrap extends SnoowrapClass {
    getContentByIds(ids: Array<string | Submission | Comment>): Promise<Listing<Submission | Comment>>
}
```

and then import from the file above where you want to use it.

Comment: It removed the typescript initial error but when I run my code I get a `Error: Cannot find module './types/snoowrap'` error.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did you find any solutions?